# LibreOffice x-axis log2

Tags: libreoffice

I'm making a chart in LibreOffice, and for my data, I want the x-axis to be a logarithmic scale, but with base 2 instead of 10. How can I do that, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, it appears to be possible to "fake it" by setting the logarithmic major interval to a value of 
[image: foo+bar]

[image]

You will likely need to modify the axis number formating as well, to prevent the axis labels from showing as ugly decimal expansions - for example, setting it to 0 or 1 decimal place.